# Projectile not working anymore. How can I reenable it?

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-prelude

When I start emacs now, prelude is no longer activated. This is my `personal.el` file:

```
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq tab-width 4)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(tab-stop-list (quote (4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76 80 84 88 92 96 100 104 108 112 116 120))))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/bin/")))
(setq auto-fill-mode -1)
(setq-default fill-column 99999)
(setq fill-column 99999)
(setq global-hl-line-mode -1)
(require 'projectile)

(defun myprojectilehook ()
  (projectile-mode)
)

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'myprojectilehook)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
```

I tried to add a hook to find-file-hook, that would enable projectile for the current buffer, but without much success. When I open emacs projectile is disabled. When I visit a new file, projectile remains disabled. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `projectile-global-mode` as well that activates Projectile everywhere there is a project context. `projectile-global-mode` is activated by default in Prelude, so I guess the real issue has to do with your Prelude setup. At any rate:

`(projectile-global-mode +1)`

should unconditionally enable projectile for all of your projects. Keep in mind that that `projectile` will always be disabled for buffers in directories that projectile doesn't consider to be projects (unless you add a `.projectile` file in them to mark the root folder of a project).

P.S. I am the author of both Prelude and Projectile, so fell free to post additional details about your problems with Prelude & Projectile here or at their respective issue trackers at GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Note that prior to Emacs 24, `(projectile-mode)` will *toggle* the mode (exactly like calling it with `M-x projectile-mode`). If it was on, that would turn it off.

Assuming it uses the standard mode definition macros, `(projectile-mode 1)` would enable, and `(projectile-mode -1)` disable.

`C-h f projectile-mode` ought to indicate this.